# Is is possible/a good idea to edit workflows in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dynamics-crm

I've been doing a lot of editing in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 using the web designer. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to edit workflows and wondering if VS 2008 could be used (and if it is more efficient). If so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create workflows in VS 2008, but it's impossible to edit workflows created by CRM. Those workflows are named No-Code Workflows, they are not supported in any ways by Microsoft and they are hard to build, deploy, and maintain.

Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/jonasd/archive/2008/01/21/Creating-a-no_2D00_code-workflow-for-CRM-4.0-with-Visual-Studio-2005-_2800_2008_2900_.aspx

I've used that to create some workflows that could not be built using the CRM interface. There is many not-documented issues when working with the deployment tool (that is integrated with VS2005 only if I remember well). It is like using a pre-beta version of a tool that no-body is using...

Comment: So, I'm guessing that the best way to edit workflows is in the CRM then? I think you can edit the XML also if you export then reimport, but that looked....interesting.

Comment: Yes that's it. And you can also edit the XML and re-import it, but it's also not supported...