# MS WF state machine workflows and MS CRM Dynamics 2011

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, state-machine-workflow

According to the answer to this question [MS WF state machine workflows and MS CRM Dynamics 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109/ms-wf-state-machine-workflows-and-ms-crm-dynamics-4-0) State machine workflows are not supported in CRM 4.0.

We are wondering if they are supported in MS CRM 2011?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create state machine workflow with Windows Workflow Foundation (platform update 1) and import it to CRM  the interesting thing is you can use CRM wait condition as trigger for your transaction, but there is a problem, it's not working when you have 2 or more parallel wait condition.